# GridViewRowCommand cant find header row textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield, header-row

i am trying to insert into sql table using gridview header template, under the gridview rowcommand i am trying to find the control and it is not able to retrieve the value.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        string NetWeightConnectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NetWeightConnectionString"].ToString();
        string query = "INSERT INTO [Net Weight Tracking] ([Date])VALUES (@Date)";
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(NetWeightConnectionStrings))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn))
        {
            String Date = ((TextBox)GridV1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBox31")).Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(((TextBox)GridV1.HeaderRow.FindControl("TextBox31")).Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
            sqlConn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            GridV1.DataSource = dt;
            GridV1.DataBind();
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: where is this TextBox31 located in the Header Row?

Comment: @Agalo it is located under HeaderTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `RowDataBound` Event to get the header template controls.

```
protected void GridView1__RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
             TextBox txtControl = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox31");
        }
     }
```

**EDIT 1**

From the link shared for the GridView Mark up, TextBox31 is not in the HeaderItemTemplate, it is in EditItemTemplate. That would be the reason, you are not able to find the textbox.

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox31" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Field4") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: but i need it under  protected void GridView1_RowCommand1(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

Comment: Updated the answer, EDIT1

Comment: no the headertemplate is indented in the pastebin, textbox31 is in the header template, please have a closer look Date field.

Comment: You have textbox31 at 2 places at lines 44, and 433.

Comment: i changed textbox values in the gridview, there are no more repeats but it still isnt fetching the values from the textbox

Comment: can you check if you are getting the control in RowDataBoundEvent, just want to make sure if the control is there and then we can make it work for RowCommand Event

Comment: No i am still not getting the textbox values from header row.